# How do I fill a combobox in QGIS with only points vector layers?

Tags: qgis, python, vector, geometry

I'm new to writing plugins in python for QGIS. I've been searching on internet for a while and wrote the code below. Even though it fills my combobox, all layers (rasters, vectors of all geometry types) get added. What am I doing wrong here?

```
#Populate the combo box with vector layers
    layers = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values()
    for layer in layers:
        if layer.type() == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer and layer.geometryType() == QGis.Point:
            self.dlg.mMapLayerComboBox.addItem(layer.name(), layer)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should help:

```
  if layer.type() == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer and (layer.wkbType()==QGis.WKBPoint or layer.wkbType() == QGis.WKBMultiPoint):
```

But it is not the best approach. Just use **QgsMapLayerComboBox**
https://qgis.org/api/classQgsMapLayerComboBox.html

use:

```
comboBox.setFilters(QgsMapLayerProxyModel.PointLayer)
```

On your combobox object.