# How do I fill a Field Combo Box with vector layer fields in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, vector, fields-attributes

I am new to python and I am trying to write my first plugin for QGIS. Earlier I asked [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/197167/how-do-i-fill-a-combobox-in-qgis-with-only-points-vector-layers) to find out how I could populate a combobox with point vector layers (and nothing else).

I've been trying to retrieve the fields of the layers and use them to populate a combobox as well. A couple hours of searching and trying have resulted in the code below. Unfortunately the combobox remains empty even though I am able to get the field names with the code below in the python console in QGIS.

```
#Fill combobox with vector layer fields.
layerFields = self.dlg.mMapLayerComboBox.currentLayer()

fields = layerFields.pendingFields()
field_names = [field.name() for field in fields]
self.dlg.mFieldComboBox.addItems(field_names)
```

Code for layer combobox:

```
layers = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values()
for layer in layers:
 self.dlg.mMapLayerComboBox.addItem(layer.name(), layer)
```

Answer: my code lacked the setLayer line. Now resulting in the code below:

```
layerFields = self.dlg.mMapLayerComboBox.currentLayer()
self.dlg.mFieldComboBox.setLayer(layer)
fields = layerFields.pendingFields()
field_names = [field.name() for field in fields]
self.dlg.mFieldComboBox.addItems(field_names)
```

Comment: This code works for me.

Comment: Added the code for the layer combobox for clarification, I guess something is still wrong there, haven't found the problem myself yet.

Comment: Agree with @dmh126 that it also works for me. When you have the Python Console open and you load your plugin, does it report any errors?

Comment: `mMapLayerComboBox` was created as `QComboBox` instance or `QgsMapLayerComboBox`?

Comment: It was created as a QgsMapLayerComboBox. And no, the console doesn't report any errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use QgsFieldComboBox instead - then all the work is already done for you, including nice features like showing the field type in an icon. See https://qgis.org/api/classQgsFieldComboBox.html

Comment: I did use QgsFieldComboBox, should it be filled automatically? Feels like I'm missing something here ;) .

Comment: Have you set the layer associated with the box using setLayer?